# Unexpected view type nested under text node: class com. facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode

Tags: react-native

I am Developing a sample Application in android when i am Developing sample .js page it's getting eroor like as show below page. please rectify this error 
this is my Code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
 /* To  View the user Bookings Screen */
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image
} from 'react-native';



class DiagnosticCalender extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <View style={{flexGrow:1,backgroundColor:'green'}}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Coming Soon
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  }
});


module.exports = DiagnosticCalender;
```

So, this my Code when i was  run the application getting this error.[image]

Comment: Any progress how to solve it?

Comment: change styles like give as container

Comment: not give flexgrow initially